# Prepend timestamp to every output line of a command

Tags: bash, posix

I have this script that should prepend the timestamp to every output line of a command:

```sh
  $command 2>&1 | while IFS= read -r line; do printf '[%s] %s\n' "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')" "$line"; done
```

It's working fine for most cases, but I have a certain case in which I have an issue.

Let's take for example this:

```sh
read -rep "Your age: " age | while IFS= read -r line; do printf '[%s] %s\n' "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')" "$line"; done
```

In this case the timestamp is not prepended.

I understand the problem here is that the newline is not reached so the newline is not printed. I was wondering if is possible to print all the chars as they are received and then print the timestamp once we get a newline.

Comment: What do you expect `read -rep "prompt string: " var_name` to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: @pilcrow just does not print the timestamp

Comment: @RamanSailopal do you have an example?

Comment: When command does not terminate its output with a newline, `read` fail and the `while` loop terminates. To avoid this, do `while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the read command is not writing anything to stout and so the while loop has no output to process and loop on. By adding an echo of the age, you get the required result.

```
read -rep "Your age: " age;
echo $age | while IFS= read -r line; 
do 
  printf '[%s] %s\n' "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')"; 
done
```

Comment: Is there a way for not wait for a newline and just print char as they are passed and then when a newline is received prepending the timestamp?